# Return to activity after Action Input Method Settings

Tags: android, android-intent, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I am making a custom keyboard app.
There is a button that leads the user from the app to `Input Method Settings`.
Here is the intent:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS), 2000);
```

Now, is there a way to return user to the activity after he enables the keyboard?
**EDIT**
Is there a way to set a BroadcastReceiver and register when the user clicks "ok" button on warning window? And then app can call super.onResume() to resume the activity.

Comment: It should come back to your activity automatically

Comment: It doesn't. When I check the keyboard in "Keyboard and input methods", a warning shows, and after that when I click ok, it stays in settings. I can only go back to the activity when I press back button.

Comment: Hi @filipst were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I simply spawn an IntentService that listens for changes at the same time I launch the Settings menu. I believe this is also how SwiftKey has done theirs.

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService
     */
    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String packageLocal = getPackageName();
        boolean isInputDeviceEnabled = false;
        while(!isInputDeviceEnabled) {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            List<InputMethodInfo> list = inputMethodManager.getEnabledInputMethodList();

            // check if our keyboard is enabled as input method
            for(InputMethodInfo inputMethod : list) {
                String packageName = inputMethod.getPackageName();
                if(packageName.equals(packageLocal)) {
                    isInputDeviceEnabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // open activity
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(newIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: How i am suppose to know if user has disabled my keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).addFlags
                (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK), 2000);
```

This should work, but note that `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` requeries >=11 api level

Comment: I am afraid that it is not working. Still no return to the app after enabling the keyboard.

Comment: Yes, but if you click back button on that menu you should go to your activity, instead of Settings, if you want to close it by just picking, i'm afraid there is no way to do that

Comment: Returning to the Action was working with the back button. But I saw in one app on the store that it can be done. I just don't know how.

Comment: @filipst Hey, do you know how do we confirm that user selected our keyboard and pressed OK button?

Comment: @Akhil Gite check the answer that I accepted. It is working.

Answer (score 0):

You can add onResume() listener, when user went to the setting to activate keyboard then you activate your any boolean varible to true  and when user return to your app then onResume() listener hit then you check your boolean variable if it's true it means user went to the setting to activate keyboad then check if the keyboard is active or not and perform your logic